# Ladon (example has syntax error)

Tags: python, web-services, ladon

(Ladon) I use the command 'serve' and get a syntax error pointing to the 'serve' keyword, I've also tried substituting the 'serve' with 'testserve' because the -ctl script has notes talking about the name change but using 'testserve' also gives the same error.  I've ladon-3.3-ctl.py and my test script is based on the Ladon's example (script name:  Calculator.py).  Can you suggest a trouble-shooting direction?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For questions about errors like what you're experiencing, please edit your question to include a code sample or provide a link where others can see your code. This will really help to get you a reliable and accurate answer for what you need. Thank you!

Comment: @brightmatrix  Hi, I tried setting up a basic web service by following [link](http://pythonhosted.org/ladon/).  After writing and running the TestService script referenced in the link, I tried running the web service via '>>> ladon-3.3-ctl.py serve testservice.py -p 8080' but I got an error pointing to the 'serve' keyword.  I also tried substituting the word with 'testserve' but I got the same error.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I tried Example 1 in the link which is the Calculator class.